# Idea: pic-of-the-week on the site blog?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, blog

What do you think about making the Picture of the Week click through to a blog post showing that photo?

- We could alter the contest slightly to ask for larger versions for this purpose — many people already do provide links to a larger version.
- We could give the photographer an opportunity to add a few lines (or paragraphs) about the image if they like.
- The post could also provide links to the photographer's blog and other recognition.
- The comments could provide a place for discussion of the image.

Comment: I really like this idea

Comment: Ditto. I think it is a great idea. I think we should start with the next weeks winner, now that we have rolling contest thread up and running.